# Blocking IP address using ufw vs blocking IP address from apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, firewall

I have a website, and I want to block specific IP address from accessing my site. I have found two ways to prevent a particular IP address.

**Using ufw**, I can execute `ufw deny from 123.123.123.123 to any port 80 proto tcp`.

Or I can add `deny from 123.123.123.123` in my apache configuration file. Which one is the best method and to avoid a specific IP address from accessing my website.

Answer (score 0):

ufw uses the kernel Netfilter for filtering traffic, that is likely to be higher performance than blocking in an application such as Apache so I would normally recommend blocking at the firewall level.